# How to call different functions based on input parameters and passing parameters

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
def fog_create_user (i,j,k):pass
def fog_delect_user ():pass
def fog_update_user ():pass
def fiqa (i.j.k):pass
def single_match ():pass
def batch_match ():pass
def verify ():pass
def create_user ():pass
def delect_user ():pass
def update_user():pass


def switch_function(input_key):
    func_dict = {
        "fog_create_user":fog_create_user,
        "fog_delect_use":fog_delect_user,
        "fog_update_user":fog_update_user,
        "fiqa":fiqa,
        "single_match":single_match,
        "batch_match":batch_match,
        "verify":verify,
        "create_user":create_user,
        "delect_user":delect_user,
        "update_user":update_user
    }
    return func_dict.get(input_key)
```

how can I exec function and passing parameters like `input_key = 'fiqa' exec fiqa(i,j.k)`

Comment: desired_func  = switch_function('fiqa'); desired_func(i,j,k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the function inline by adding the parameters afterwards

```
switch_function("fiqa")(1,2,3)
```

Or, if you are trying to to call the required function directly then this might be what you are looking for

```
def exec_function(input_key, *params):
    func_dict = {
        "fog_create_user":fog_create_user,
        "fog_delect_use":fog_delect_user,
        "fog_update_user":fog_update_user,
        "fiqa":fiqa,
        "single_match":single_match,
        "batch_match":batch_match,
        "verify":verify,
        "create_user":create_user,
        "delect_user":delect_user,
        "update_user":update_user
    }
    func = func_dict.get(input_key)
    return func(*params)

exec_function("fiqa",4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#take user input (assuming "fiqa")
function_name = "fiqa"

#returns the function
function_to_call = switch_function(function_name)

#call the function
function_to_call(i,j,k)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflections, if you wrap the functions into a class, you can use the function

```
getattr()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-getattr-method/

to call function as string parameter with its parameters

```
class YourClass():

    def __init__(self):pass
    def fog_create_user (i,j,k):pass
    def fog_delect_user ():pass
    def fog_update_user ():pass
    def fiqa (i.j.k):pass
    def single_match ():pass
    def batch_match ():pass
    def verify ():pass
    def create_user ():pass
    def delect_user ():pass
    def update_user():pass


def switch_function(input_key):
     obj = YourClass()
     for name in .__dict__.items() :
         if type(name) == FunctionType:
             getattr(obj, name)
```

Note: the code is not tested. The methods can also be called with parameters, additional checks need to be done, or make the parameters class attributesand give them default values.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, but this answer does a terrible job at explaining it, and should perhaps be a comment instead.

Comment: The link sends to the explanation. Sure, probably as a comment might have sufficed, I'll keep it in mind for future responses